# Is it possible that showing progress dialog on tab?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to show progress dialog on tab, so that i can change tabs. My progress bar show on full screen, so that i can not change tabs.

Comment: here is below link that can help you to achieve your goal http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ofcourse you can display **Progress Dialog with `setCancelable(false)`** so that user can not change tabs.

But What the problem you are getting while showing progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

ProgressDialog requires context of currently displayed window, and I think you are following TabGroupActivity Sample, you should Initialize ProgressDialog by following statement:

```
ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "title", "message");
```